# How to use GetPixel for Bitmap() in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim terrain As Bitmap(500, 500)
        terrain = New Bitmap(500, 500)
        terrain.GetPixel(250, 250)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code and I get an error saying `GetPixel is not a member of Bitmap()`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please, fault me for anything i'm doing wrong here, I've never coded in VB before.

Comment: As the error message says, `Bitmap` does not have a member called `GetPixel`. What is it that you want `terrain.GetPixel(250, 250)` to do?

Comment: Since you say you haven't coded with VB.net you should know some things.
The get pixel and set pixel functions are incredibly slow. I understand that they are somewhat easier to use but you will surely get a headache eventually. 
A much faster approach is to use lockbits and iterate through the collection yourself. 
Someone made a nice little project on this site and called the class FastPixel. Search for that and you'll find a nice demo on the topic with good bits of info on how it all works.
I know this doesn't answer your question but figure you might like the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesleron

I am not sure with the code you pasted if you have everything that is required.

Here is an example of the code that is need that you can use the Bitmap in Visual Basic.

First you need to add the "Imports System.Drawing"

Here is an example of code you will need to use bitmap.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Drawing

Namespace Rextester
    Public Module Program
        Public Sub Main(args() As string)
            'Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!")

            Try
        ' Retrieve the image.
        Dim image1 = New Bitmap( _
            "C:\temp\Grapes.jpg", _
            True)

        Dim x, y As Integer

        ' Loop through the images pixels to reset color.
        For x = 0 To image1.Width - 1
            For y = 0 To image1.Height - 1
                Dim pixelColor As Color = image1.GetPixel(x, y)
                Dim newColor As Color = _
                    Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 0, 0)
                image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor)
            Next
        Next

        ' Set the PictureBox to display the image.
        Console.WriteLine(image1)

        ' Display the pixel format in Label1.
        Console.Writeline("Pixel format: " + image1.PixelFormat.ToString())

    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        Console.Writeline("There was an error." _
            & "Check the path to the image file.")
    End Try
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```